# Custom display with realtime CANBUS values being shown

Tags: linux

How does one go about using a Raspberry Pi to display a custom display of analogue gauges and values that are sent to the Pi via CANBUS from a vehicles ECU? What software/tools are needed to write the graphics and real time values that are wanting to be displayed?

I've read so far that a server needs to be installed and running for the values to be updated and output live as they occur. Is this correct?

I'm just starting out on this project and looking to be pointed in the right direction.

Thanks